# getting users recent(newly addes) posts

Tags: php, json, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I'm working with facecook php sdk and I want to get users status updates in last 30 mints. I'm new to this sdk an still I'm learing this. Is there a way where can I get users recent facebook status?

I'm using the below code and this gives all the status updates. I want to get only the recent updates.

```
  $request = new FacebookRequest($sess,'GET','/me/posts');
  $response = $request->execute();
  $graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();

            echo '<pre>' . print_r( $graphObject, 1 ) . '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need the `user_posts` permission via the Login, then you can use the `since` parameter together with a time calculation in PHP to get the timestamp from 30min ago

```
/me/posts?since={timestamp_30min_ago}
```

Replace `{timestamp_30min_ago}` with the actual timestamp.

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.3#reference-user_posts
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.3#paging
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php